# Programmatic calculation of Kubernetes Limit Range

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a way to calculate appropriate [Limit Range](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) and [Resource Quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/) settings for Kubernetes based on the sizing of our Load Test (LT) environment. The LT environment we want to keep flexible in order to play with things and I feel that's a great way to figure out how to set up the limits, etc.

I might also have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this works, so feel free to correct that.

Does anyone have a set of equations or anything that takes into account (I know it won't be an exact science, but I am looking mostly for a jumping-off point):

1. Container CPU
2. Container memory

Right now I am pulling the CPU limits requested using this (and the memory similarly, and using some  nifty shell script things I found to do full calculations for me):

```bash
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[].resource.limits.cpu}{"\n"}{end}' -n my-namespace
```

We made sure all of our containers are explicitly making requests for CPU/memory, so that works nicely.

The machine type is based on our testing and target number of pods per node. We have [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) declarations in use as we need to separate things out for some very specific needs by the services being deployed and to be able to leverage multiple machine types.

For the **Limit Range** I was thinking (adding 10% just for padding):

> Maximum [CPU/memory] + 10% (ensuring that the machine type holds 2x that calculation) as:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: LimitRange
> metadata:
>   name: ns-my-namespace
>   namespace: my-namespace
> spec:
>   limits:
>   - max:
>       cpu: [calculation_from_above]
>       memory: [calculation_from_above]
>     type: Container
> ```

For the **Resource Quota** I was thinking (50% to handle estimated overflow in "emergency" [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)):

> Total of all CPU/memory in the Load Test environment + 50% as:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ResourceQuota
> metadata:
>   name: ns-my-namespace
>   namespace: my-namespace
> spec:
>   hard:
>     limits:
>       cpu: [calculation_from_above]
>       memory: [calculation_from_above]
> ```